# Need Help to design an autonomous robot

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, mapping, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to design an autonomous robot it will be a simple robot for indoor mapping and navigation, Please suggest:

1. which sensor to be used Lidar or kinect?
2. from where I can start? I don't understand that how to do map, how to write codes for mapping?
   and where I can write code. please suggest I'll be greatfull for your reply.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276349/need-help-to-design-an-autonomous-robot/) by [Hassam](https://answers.ros.org/users/32669/hassam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. For the sensor you need to decide whether you need a 2D map of the environment or 3D. For 2D case you can opt for laser range finder (lidar) and in case you need a 3D map you can utilize kinect.
2. To start with mapping there is a lot of literature available. I would recommend you to start looking up theory for SLAM.
   Some of the links I found useful [link text](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws13/mapping/) . [Here](http://sauravag.com/)  you can find step by step progress of working with mapping module as mentioned by Saurav.
3. For completely autonomous robot you need to look at path planning stuff too. You can have a look at [Computational Motion planning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-motion-planning) course at coursera for some insight.

---

Originally posted by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) with karma: 225 on 2017-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1